# Error configuring alfresco community edition to cmis

Tags: alfresco, cmis

I have just get-started with Alfresco Community Edition 5.0.0b and trying to do handshake with apache cmis to alfresco.

Referring to multiple sources and this doc http://ecmarchitect.com/images/articles/cmis/cmis-article.pdf

I am now able to authenticate through GET request at

```
http://<IP Address>:8080/alfresco/s/api/login?u=admin&pw=admin
```

and fetch the token for each successive request. I am looking for atom-public-url where I need to pass the username and password to move on with content management.

But, I am unable to hit cmis URL on alfresco. Tried multiple URLs like

```
http://<IP Address>:8080/alfresco/s/cmis
http://<IP Address>:8080/alfresco/api/cmis
```

and likewise, but nothing works so far.

I am getting 404 with following message each time

```
Message:    10140008 Script url /cmis does not map to a Web Script.
```

Any help appreciated! Please let me know if I missed anything ..

P.S. After the fresh install of alfresco I have by default 403 Web Scripts available but none with above matching /cmis

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those are the wrong CMIS endpoints for Alfresco 5.0. You instead need to use one of

```
http://localhost:8080/alfresco/api/-default-/public/cmis/versions/1.0/atom
http://localhost:8080/alfresco/api/-default-/public/cmis/versions/1.1/atom
```

Depending on if you want to use CMIS 1.0 or 1.1 support

You can find the per-Alfresco-version CMIS endpoint URLs on the [Alfresco Wiki](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/CMIS#CMIS_Service_URL)